# How to include style sheet only on pages in a certain Area in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have a style sheet that I only want included on web pages that are a part of a specific Area in MVC.

I know, by default, you get `Areas/<Area Name>/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml`, but I want the default layout rendered for this area. My Area's _ViewStart file looks like:

```
@ {
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

I tried adding a call to `Styles.Render("My Bundle Name")` in the _ViewStart file for my Area, but the `<link>` tag is not showing up in the HTML source.

I even created an `HtmlHelper` extension method that returns the name of the current Area in MVC from the Route, and including the stylesheet that way:

```
@if (Html.AreaName() == "MyArea")
{
    @Styles.Render("...")
}
```

Code for the `AreaName()` extension method:

```
public static string AreaName<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper)
{
    return htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["area"] as string;
}
```

But this always returns null. I even debugged the application and poked around the "Locals" debugger tab. The route data contains the controller, id and action name, but not the area name even though it's rendering a page in my area.

**Background**

I am creating a NuGet package for this area that can be installed on any MVC application. In our organization, we are given a basic HTML and CSS layout based on Bootstrap, so there is some predictability with layout, but I'd like to hedge my bets and only import styles specific to my Area on pages rendered from that Area.

**How can I include a style sheet for pages in one certain Area in MVC, that doesn't show up in other Areas, or pages with no Area?**

Comment: If you're using `"~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"` as your layout for this area, have you tried using `Styles.Render("My Bundle Name")` in the `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` file?

Comment: @Gavin: That will work, however then this style sheet is on every page in the site. I only want the style sheet imported for pages under my area.

Comment: overriding css classes right by specifying it for each elements. I suppose it's not an option for you ?¸

Comment: @AntoinePelletier: I don't want the styles for pages in this area polluting the main site's styles. They need to be in separate style sheets, and only imported on pages rendered as part of this Area in MVC.

Comment: Why not create a layout for your area and use that for views from that area ?

Comment: @GregBurghardt: I see. Then you may want to consider making separate layouts for each area. I don't know if there would be any other way to get stylesheets to blanket an entire area without including them in each file.

Comment: @Shyju: Because the layout for my area needs to match the layout of the main site.

Comment: But you want to add the if condition check in the main layout then ? What is the `Html.AreaName()` doing  ? Where is the code for that ?

Comment: @Shyju: Updated my queston with code for the AreaName extension method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the area name from `DataTokens`

This should work.

```
public static string AreaName<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper)
{
    return htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] as string;
}
```

Comment: i tried this code(in an mvc5 app) and it worked. I invoked the method like this `@if (String.Equals(Html.AreaName(),"MyArea")) {  //stuff goes here }`

Comment: Shouldn't it stay in the main project as you are calling this method in the layout (part of main project) anyway ?

Comment: So I'm a complete id10t. In my nuget package of HtmlHelper extensions I wasn't returning `DataTokens["area"]` and instead was returning `Values["area"]` like I had originally. This happens when I think I've copied and pasted, and I actually haven't. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not an elegant solution, but you could set a `PageData` value in your `ViewStart` and then check for it in the main `Layout` page:

**_ViewStart.cshtml for your area**

```
@{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
   PageData["AdditionalStyleBundle"] = "~/Content/myCSSBundle";
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<head>
    @if (PageData.ContainsKey("AdditionalStyleBundle"))
    {
       @Styles.Render(PageData["AdditionalStyleBundle"]);
    }
</head>
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution, actually. It's one I'm going to keep in mind for the future.